# Angular Edit 400 status Crud

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, crud, formgroups

hello guys i have problem using angular spring boot ,
For spring boot : backend
when i try to make edit request using spring boot without puting the id i got status 500 , so i add the id using swagger and it's working ( on backend )

For Angular : FrontEnd
i need to add the Id to reportForm this is my code but i always get 400 status
so i think i should add id to updatedData ( as it's working with swagger )
[angular Status 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7H7r.png)

My code ts :

```
  UpdateReport(): void {
    console.log(this.reportId);
    this.reportForm.patchValue({id:this.reportId});
    if (this.reportForm.valid) {
      
      // Log the reportForm data to verify that 'id' is included
      console.log('reportForm Data:', this.reportForm.value);

      this.reportService.updateReport(this.reportId, this.reportForm.value).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log('Report updated successfully', response);
          this.router.navigate(['/listreport']);
        },
        error => console.error('Error updating report', error)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

my service code :

```
  updateReport(reportId: number, updatedData: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/update/${reportId}`, updatedData);
  }
```

[when i try to edit report without id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0RrB.png)
[swagger error 500 when i don't put id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrKCJ.png)

[backend working when i add id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZtX3.png)

i try to patch the id value into reportForm ,
this is my code report form :

```
 // Initialize the form here
    this.reportForm = new FormGroup({
      chambre: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      problem: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(''),
      dateReport: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    }
```

[report form angular vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CLtr.png)

Comment: your angular would spawn json like this `{chambre, problem, description, dateReport}`, but it seems your backend wants `{chambre: {idChambre}, problem description, dateReport}` or something. your screenshot are not full. but it is obvious that you are not creating object of the right shape

Comment: yes that's my problem how can i add chambre : {idChambre} on body updatedData
  UpdateReport(): void {
    if (this.reportForm.valid) {
      console.log('reportForm Data:', this.reportForm.value);
      this.reportService.updateReport(this.reportId, this.reportForm.value).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log('Report updated successfully', response);
          this.router.navigate(['/listreport']);
        },
        error => console.error('Error updating report', error)
      );
    }
  }